# How to replace token in a file using gradle?

Tags: gradle, token

In folder where gradle build file is present, I have file named "file" and it has following data :

```
@tokenval@
```

In build file I have following thing written :

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.*
task processResources  {
    filesMatching('file') {
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [tokenval:  1])
    }
}
```

I want to replace @tokenval@ in file with 1. But it's giving following error when i run using  gradle -q processResources :

```
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'gradle learning experiments'.
> Could not find method filesMatching() for arguments [file, build_biz3ipxhnv8xkmjuuxur85z50$_run_closure1$_closure2@7d811b8] on task ':processResources' of type org.gradle.api.DefaultTask.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will copy the input `file` to the project `build/` directory and replace the token in the copy:

```groovy
import org.apache.tools.ant.filters.*
task processResources(type: Copy)  {
    from('file') {
        filter(ReplaceTokens, tokens: [tokenval:  '1'])
    }
    into(buildDir)
}
```